# R – How to give a common ID to matching data with close value, and arrange dataframe for paired tests (ex from Hmisc::find.matches() )

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, output, matching

*Hi everyone ! I hope you are having a great day.*

**Aim and context**

My two dataframes are built from different methods, but measure the same parameters on the same signals.
I’d like to match every signals in the first dataframe with the same signal in the second dataframe, to compare the parameter values, and evaluate the methods against each other.

I would gratefully appreciate any help, as I reached my beginner’s limits in R coding but also in dataframe management.

Basically, I would like to find matches in two separate dataframes and consider that the matches are refering to the same entity (for instance along the creation an ID variable), in order to perform statistical analysis for paired data.

I could have made the matches by hand on a spreadsheet, but because there are hundreds of entries and more comparisons to come, I’d like to automatize the matching and creation of dataframe.

To give you an idea, my dataframes look like this :

*DF1*

| *Recording* | *Selection* | *Start (ms)* | *Freq.max (kHz)* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 11.3 | 42.4 |
| 001 | 2 | 122.9 | 46.2 |
| 001 | 3 | 232.3 | 47.5 |
| 002 | 1 | 22.9 | 30.9 |
| 002 | 2 | 512.4 | 31.3 |

My second dataframe would look something like this :

*DF2*

| *Recording* | *Selection* | *Start (ms)* | *Freq.max (kHz)* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | 10.9 | 41.8 |
| 001 | 2 | 122.1 | 44.5 |
| 001 | 3 | 231.3 | 44.4 |
| 002 | 1 | 513.0 | 30.2 |

**My ideas**

I thought about identifying each signal, **but**

- An ID using "Recording + selection" (001_1, 001_2...) would not work because some signals are not detected in both methods.
- So I'd want to use the start position to identify the signals, but rounding to the closest or upper/lower value would not match all the signals.

**Hmisc::find.matches() function**

I tried the function find.matches() from the package Hmisc, that gives the matches of your columns, given the tolerance threshold you input.

`find <- find.matches(DF_method1$start_one, DF_method2$start_two, tol=(2))`
*(I arbitrarily chose a tolerance of 2 ms, for it to be considered as the same signal)*

The output looks like this :

```
Matches:
    Match #1   Match #2   Match #3
[1,]        1        7        0
[2,]        2       42        0
[3,]        3        0        0
[4,]        4        0        0
[5,]        0        0        0
[6,]        5        0        0
[7,]       22        6        0
```

I feel like it is coming together but I am stuck to these two questions :

- How to find the closest match among each recording, not comparing all signals in all recordings ? (example here, all 1st matches are correctly identified, except n°7, matched with n°22, which is from a different recording) ***How could I run the function, within each recording*** ?
- ***How to create a dataframe from the output*** ? Which would be a dataframe with only the signals that had a match and their related parameter values.

I feel like this function gets close to my aim but if you have any other suggestion, I am all ears.

*Thanks a lot*